# understanding a mathematica equation

Tags: functions

I have found the equation below written with Mathematica, I looked at the Mathematica online guide but it is still difficult to understand the equation. Can someone write this (or part of it) in simple math using latex, please.

```
n[r_] := Sum[ 1 + 2 Floor[Sqrt[r^2 - 3 x^2]],
           {x, -Floor[r/Sqrt[3]], Floor[r/Sqrt[3]]}
         ] + Sum[2 Floor[ Sqrt[r^2 - 3 x^2] + 1/2],
           {x, -Floor[(r/Sqrt[3]) + 1/2] + 1/2, Floor[(r/Sqrt[3]) + 1/2] - 1/2}
         ]
```

Answer (score 8):

In Mathematica you can use $\it{\text{expression // TeXForm}}$ to get the TeX code for any mathematical expression you have written down (also works nicely for arrays and matrices). For your problem

```
   Sum[ 1 + 2 Floor[Sqrt[r^2 - 3 x^2]], {x, -Floor[r/Sqrt[3]], 
   Floor[r/Sqrt[3]]}] + Sum[2 Floor[ Sqrt[r^2 - 3 x^2] + 1/2], 
   {x, -Floor[(r/Sqrt[3]) + 1/2] + 1/2, Floor[(r/Sqrt[3]) + 1/2] 
  - 1/2}] // TeXForm
```

gives us:

$$\sum _{x=-\left\lfloor \frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}\right\rfloor }^{\left\lfloor
   \frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}\right\rfloor } \left(2 \left\lfloor \sqrt{r^2-3
   x^2}\right\rfloor +1\right)+\sum _{x=\frac{1}{2}-\left\lfloor
   \frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor }^{\left\lfloor
   \frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor -\frac{1}{2}} 2 \left\lfloor
   \sqrt{r^2-3 x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you add n[r_] := at the beginning, what does it give?

Comment: @BenBost With $:=$ it does not work. With $n[r\_] = \ldots$ it gives us exactly the same.

Comment: @BenBost btw the expression looks like it is approximating the area of a circle. We have $n(r) \sim \frac{2\pi r^2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: yes! it gives the number of hexagonal lattice points in a circle.

Comment: actually you mean $n(r) = \frac{2\pi r^2}{\sqrt{3}}$ when $r$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: @BenBost Sort of. $\sim$ means asymptotially, i.e. $\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{n(r)}{ 2\pi r^2/\sqrt{3}} = 1$.

Comment: In fact, in the equation it is assumed the lattice is generated by (0,1) and ($\sqrt{3}$/2,1/2), then the first sum counts the number of points of the form ($\sqrt{3}$x,y) where x,y $\in$ ℤ, $\sqrt{3}x$ $\leq$ r, and 3$x^2$+$y^2 \leq r^2$. The second sum counts the number of points of the form ($\sqrt{3}$x,y) where x,y $\in$(ℤ+1/2), $\sqrt{3} \leq r$, and 3$x^2$+$y^2 \leq r^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24087/discussion-between-ben-bost-and-winther).

Comment: I know that it is not related to the question but do you have any suggestions how to transform this equation for a lattice when the distance between the lattice points is a given parameter d.

Comment: @BenBost: Scale the radius by $d$?

Comment: @BenBost Yes, that works.

Comment: @Winther: Do you mean dividig $r$ by $d$? I mean is the following equation for counting the number of lattice points when the distance between lattice points is $d$, correct?

$$n(r) = \sum_{x=-\lfloor \frac{r}{d\sqrt{3}}\rfloor}^{\lfloor \frac{r}{d\sqrt{3}}\rfloor} (2\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{d^2}-3x^2} \rfloor+1) + \sum_{x=\frac{1}{2}-\lfloor \frac{r}{d\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor}^{\lfloor \frac{r}{d\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}} 2\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{r^2}{d^2}-3x^2} +\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$$

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Do you mean dividing $r$ by $d$. As I wrote in my last comment to Winther?

Answer (score 2):

Using `TeXForm` as Winther suggests is one option, but you need then to process the LaTeX output. A more direct approach to show `expression` in traditional form is `TraditionalForm[expression]` or, equivalently, `expression // TraditionalForm`. Note that you cannot append this by `n[r_]:=` because you do not want to assign a graphical output to `n[r]`.